# Como criar atalho na área de trabalho de um site quando estiver usando o chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Gostaria de sugerir para o usuário quando ele entrar no meu sistema criar um atalho do site no computador dele, isso pode ser feito manualmente indo em `"Mais Ferramentas -> Adicionar a área de trabalho"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia fazer isso programaticamente? existe alguma api do chrome ou função nativa que permita?

Comment: Isso não é possível apenas com JavaScript, provavelmente por questões de segurança.

Comment: Poderia ser feito como Notifications API, mostrar uma notificação pedindo permissão, seguindo esse formato não haveria problema algum de segurança, o problema é forçar o usuário a criar um atalho.

Comment: Também é possível fazer isso utilizando Progressive Web Apps - PWA.

Answer (score -1):

Cara se eu fosse você eu faria um arquivo `.bat` e chamaria a execução dele com o Javascript.

O arquivo Javascript:

```
var objetoMan = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("c:\\temp\\SeuArquivo.bat");
```

O arquivo `.bat`:

```
copy \\server\programa\NomeDoAtalho.lnk %userprofile%\desktop
```